# JUnit 5 and Mockito

Tags: java, maven, mockito, junit5

With Java 14 and JUnit 5, if I add mockito-junit-jupiter to my build, an error is thrown when trying to run mvn test even without using mockito in any tests. Wiithout mockito-junit-jupiter everything is okay. All dependencies are the latest versions except Maven.

The error thrown is

```
    # Created at 2020-04-15T16:34:33.816
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:189)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ReflectiveInvocationContext
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.<clinit>(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:81)


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-suite-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-runner -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: remove platform-commons, platform-suite-api etc. only keep `junit-jupiter-api` or `junit-jupiter-engine` depending on the surefire plugin version you are using which I can't see cause you haven't posted the full pom file... Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: I removed those 2 dependencies and the problem is the same. Surefire version is 3.0.0-M4

Comment: Without the full pom or even better with an example project it's more or less impossible to help...

Comment: The full pom is too large for a comment. What part are you interested in? I know the problem appears after adding the mockito-junit-jupiter dependency.

Comment: I will shorten the pom and repost everything as a new question, later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of Maven dependencies seems to be important when mixing JUnit 5 and Mockito. The Mockito dependencies MUST come after the ones for JUnit 5. Maybe it is only the one for mockito-junit-jupiter, but I try to group them toegether.