# Junit 5 with Mockito java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryListener()

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm trying to upgrade from Junit 4 to Junit 5 so we are using Mockito in our tests so to replace Run with we must add  `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)` and we added this to dependencies

`testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.3.3")`

and we have this in gradle we added this

```
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    exclude(group = "junit", module = "junit")
}
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2")
```

and after we run this test class with Mockito we got this error

```
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryListener org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryListener()'
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:44)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:63)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

I saw this [question (JUnit 5 and Mockito)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253594/junit-5-and-mockito)  and verified answer but didn't work form me as well

**Update 1**

here is the whole build.gradle

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.7.RELEASE"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.50"
}

group = "-"
version = System.getenv("VERSION") ?: "local"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_12

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  .
  .
  .
  .


  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2")

  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    exclude(group = "junit", module = "junit")
  }
  testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.3.3")


}
```

Comment: can you add dependency `testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0-M1'`. By the way, do you really want to work with a milestone version?

Comment: I will update it as I was working with 5.6.2 as well but not working

Comment: @Michael Note `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:<version>` should include `junit-jupiter-api`, `junit-jupiter-params`, and `junit-jupiter-engine` (see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-jupiter).

Comment: @Sattar good point!. Did you enable native junit support in gradle by adding `test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}` to `build.gradle`? Can you share your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz I update the question but no I didn't enable it where I should put it?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz when I added this testRutimeOnly I got another error 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/discovery/SelectorResolver

Comment: @Sattar try o put it at root level.

Comment: @MichaelKreutz  enabled it but same error

Comment: @Sattar can you share a test? A minimal example that does not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212778/discussion-between-sattar-and-michael-kreutz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your `build.gradle` as far as I can see:

1. Mockito version is not compatible with junit version -> Please remove explicit version in mockito-depedency
2. My IDE complained also about using `kotlin()` in `plugins`. -> Please change to id
3. Native support for junit is missing -> Please enable it
4. My IDE also complained about how you excluded the junit 4 dependencies

In the following `build.gradle` I have fixed these issues:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.50'
}

group = "-"
version = System.getenv("VERSION") ?: "local"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_12

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group : "org.junit.vintage", module : "junit-vintage-engine"
        exclude group : "junit", module : "junit"
    }
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter")
}
```